# Find element within table cell in webdriver using java

Tags: webdriver, element, cell, clickable

I want to check if there is a clickable image present in the table cell.

```
    If(clickable image present)
    {
     //
    }
    else
    {
     //
    }
```

How do I do it in webdriver using Java?

Answer (score 0):

Does your image tag have a name or id associated with it ?? Please post some code to help us help you.
in that case use

```
WebElement image = driver.findElement(By.name("imagename"));
image.click();
```

or

```
 WebElement image = driver.findElement(By.id("imageid"));
    image.click();
```

This identification can be done on name,id,class,xpath etc.
If not you may have to use xpath or css selectors

```
   WebElement image = driver.findElement(By.xpath("xpath"));
    image.click();
```

You can check if the image is clickable by using

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(yourWebDriver, 5);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//xpath_to_element"));
```

and then perform `element.click()`.

Comment: This is the path of the cell                                             //*[@id='ctl00_MainBody_grdStandards']/tbody/tr[10]/td[2] and this is the path of the image which I want to check : //*[@id='ctl00_MainBody_grdStandards']/tbody/tr[10]/td[2]/img[1]

Comment: The path of the image keeps on changing with every cell.

Comment: In that case iterate over tr and tds